# Energy and power of the product of an exponential and sinusoidal signal

Tags: signal-analysis

Can somebody guide me on how I can find the energy and power of the signal $$x(t)=e^{-10t}\cos(30\pi t)u(t).$$

Whether we have to split the $\cos$ to exponential and solve or go with the usual method of solving, both seems to be challenging.

Comment: Do you need to calculate using formulas or with a program tool?

Comment: [Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing))

Comment: [relation between power and energy](http://www.scienceprog.com/signal-power-and-energy-calculation/)

Comment: i have to calculate ,can you suggest me how to start?

Comment: These are the equations needed. From here this is strictly a math problem. you can either move it to the [mathematics stack exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/), where i will be more then happy to answer as well, or better yet try it yourself. Don't forget to edit the question as a math problem.

Comment: Show us where you're stuck, otherwise we can just tell you "use the right formula and evaluate", but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Also it's not clear to me what you mean by the "usual method of solving".

Comment: i stuck here calculating the integral part actually.E=∫e^-20tcos^2(30pi t.)dt from -infinty to infinty.

Comment: From *zero* to infinity (don't forget the step $u(t)$)! Just use an integral table if you can't solve it on your own; that's a pretty standard integral.

Comment: ok,Roger that and thanks once again for the help.

Comment: @Aneil did you get it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's write the signal $x(t)$ in the general form

$$x(t)=e^{-\alpha t}\cos(\omega_0t)u(t)\tag{1}$$

Note that its energy is given by

$$E_x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^2dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\alpha t}\cos^2(\omega_0)tdt\tag{2}$$

Since this is a homework type problem I won't solve it for you but I'll give you some hints:

1. Expand the integrand of $(2)$ as
   $$e^{-2\alpha t}\frac12(1+\cos(2\omega_0t))=\frac12e^{-2\alpha t}+\frac12e^{-2\alpha t}\frac12(e^{j2\omega_0t}+e^{-j2\omega_0t})$$
2. Now you have two integrals over basic exponential functions, which should be very straightforward to solve.
3. The final result should be
   $$E_x=\frac{1}{4\alpha}+\frac{\alpha}{4(\alpha^2+\omega_0^2)}$$
4. If the energy $E_x$ is finite, what can you conclude about the power of $x(t)$?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Given the level of the question, I'm pretty sure that the OP doesn't mean some kind of short-term power as a function of $t$, but the total power of the signal. Since $x(t)$ is an energy signal, we know what the power will be ...

Comment: power has to be sliding, a function of $t$.  half of the magnitude-square of the analytic signal is one way.  or the short-term local mean of the $|x(t)|^2$ above.  either way, power will be about $\frac12 e^{-2\alpha t} u(t)$.

Comment: Matt L ,i dont know how you arrived at the 2nd part of the result,i can easily get i/4a but the other part,how can you solve me,i am confused because we have to take real part but exponential that you splitted has imaginary too.If you can just give me idea about the real part of of e^(a+ib) also i can move ahead clear on that part.please.

Comment: @Aneil: Just solve the two complex integrals, and of course the result of each of them will be complex. But once you add them up you'll see that the imaginary parts cancel out and the result is real-valued. Just do it carefully and you'll arrive at the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

$x(t)=e^{-\alpha t}\sin(\omega_0t)u(t)$ is called damped sine wave. Its Fourier transform is $$X(j\omega)=\frac{\omega_0}{(\alpha+j\omega)^2+\omega_0^2}$$
A straightforward approach to calculate the signal energy is to use Parseval's identity to calculate the enery of this signal:

$$E=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert x(t)\rvert^2dt=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert X(j\omega)\rvert^2d\omega$$

If we have $\omega_0>>\alpha$, then the spectrum has a sharp peak near $\pm \omega_0$. So for instance around $\omega_0$ we can do

$$\lvert X(j\omega)\rvert\approx\frac{1/2}{\sqrt{(\omega-\omega_0)^2+\alpha^2}}$$
and by integrating we will get to the following result $$E\approx \frac {1}{8\alpha}+\frac {1}{8\alpha}=\frac {1}{4\alpha}$$

Regarding power of the signal, since this is an energy signal (i.e. a signal with bounded energy), then its power is zero. The opposite case would be a power signal (i.e. a signal with non-zero and bounded power) whose energy is infinite. An example of such power signals are periodic signals such as sine and cosine (one or two-sided).

Note that when $\alpha\to 0$, this signal tends to a power signal (a pure sine wave), and consequently $E\to\infty$

Comment: I don't think that using Parseval's indentity makes things much easier here. Can you show how you arrive at the (approximate) result?

Comment: using Parseval makes the problem harder.  both for instantaneous power and for energy.

Comment: Maybe. However, looking at the spectrum adds a level of confidence to make sure everything is fine. The final result is generic though. Of course, one may get a similar result in time domain.